# FusionCharts on iOS: Invisible second chart

Tags: ios, fusioncharts

I'm using FusionCharts on an iOS application.

Currently I have a view controller with two different UIWebViews that are loading two different charts from different html files.

The problem is that both charts are rendered but one of them is invisible as you can see in the screenshot.

It only works with one chart at a time. How can I fix this?!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfw3a.png)

Comment: Did you check if there is a duplicate ID? Are you using the latest FusionCharts (3.3.0.18739)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem this issue is is with UIWebView it self for clear explanation check out below link
http://double-slash.net/2010/10/18/using-multiple-ios-uiwebview-objects/ It can be fixed in two way by adopting a spin lock mechanism or increasing rendering time of run loop by customize the UIWebview.
         enter code here

```
@interface FCXTCustomWebView ()

@property (assign) id idelegate;

@end

@implementation FCXTCustomWebView

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    self.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self)
{
    self.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)delegate
{
 _idelegate = delegate;
}

- (void)stopRunLoop
{
CFRunLoopRef runLoop = [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop];
CFRunLoopStop(runLoop);
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];

if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:didFailLoadWithError:)])
{
    [_idelegate webView:webView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)])
{
    return [_idelegate webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
else
{
    return YES;
}
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];

if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidFinishLoad:)])
{
    [_idelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
}
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop)])
{
    [_idelegate webViewDidStartLoad:webView];
}
}

- (void) loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
[super loadHTMLString:string baseURL:baseURL];
CFRunLoopRunInMode((CFStringRef)NSDefaultRunLoopMode, 1.5, NO);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This reply might be too late. I encountered the same issue with HighCharts. 
You need not subclass UIWebView. You need to have different Javascript files for the each graph. That would work.